# How can I add data-cookieconsent="statistics" to script tag?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

On my WordPress website a plugin I'm using creates a script. This is the snippet of the plugin.

```
<!-- Start of Async Drift Code -->
<script>
"use strict";

!function() {
  var t = window.driftt = window.drift = window.driftt || [];
  if (!t.init) {
    if (t.invoked) return void (window.console && console.error && console.error("Drift snippet included twice."));
    t.invoked = !0, t.methods = [ "identify", "config", "track", "reset", "debug", "show", "ping", "page", "hide", "off", "on" ], 
    t.factory = function(e) {
      return function() {
        var n = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        return n.unshift(e), t.push(n), t;
      };
    }, t.methods.forEach(function(e) {
      t[e] = t.factory(e);
    }), t.load = function(t) {
      var e = 3e5, n = Math.ceil(new Date() / e) * e, o = document.createElement("script");
      o.type = "text/plain", o.crossorigin = "anonymous", o.async = !0, o.src = "https://js.driftt.com/include/" + n + "/" + t + ".js";
      var i = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
      i.parentNode.insertBefore(o, i);
    };
  }
}();
drift.SNIPPET_VERSION = '0.3.1';
drift.load('33xndb9yn9ha');
</script>
<!-- End of Async Drift Code -->
```

I want to enable prior consent for this script for [CookieBot](https://www.cookiebot.com/en/help/)  to do so the script should look like this

```
<script type="text/plain" data-cookieconsent="statistics" src="where/ever"></script>
```

I tried to simply add it with o.data-cookieconsent="statistics like so:

```
   <!-- Start of Async Drift Code -->
<script>
"use strict";

!function() {
  var t = window.driftt = window.drift = window.driftt || [];
  if (!t.init) {
    if (t.invoked) return void (window.console && console.error && console.error("Drift snippet included twice."));
    t.invoked = !0, t.methods = [ "identify", "config", "track", "reset", "debug", "show", "ping", "page", "hide", "off", "on" ], 
    t.factory = function(e) {
      return function() {
        var n = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        return n.unshift(e), t.push(n), t;
      };
    }, t.methods.forEach(function(e) {
      t[e] = t.factory(e);
    }), t.load = function(t) {
      var e = 3e5, n = Math.ceil(new Date() / e) * e, o = document.createElement("script");
      o.type = "text/plain", o.crossorigin = "anonymous", o.async = !0,  o.data-cookieconsent="statistics", o.src = "https://js.driftt.com/include/" + n + "/" + t + ".js";
      var i = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
      i.parentNode.insertBefore(o, i);
    };
  }
}();
drift.SNIPPET_VERSION = '0.3.1';
drift.load('33xndb9yn9ha');
</script>
<!-- End of Async Drift Code -->
```

But I get this error in the console: Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
Any guidance on what I'm doing wrong or how to properly add data-cookieconsent="statistics" is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can't have `-` in property name when using dot notation. Would be `o['data-cookieconsent']='...'`  but might need to use `setAttribute()`

Comment: `o.dataset.cookieconsent="statistics"`

Comment: Thank you this works flawlessly now @charlietfl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mentioned by Charlietfl in the comments the problem was dot notation cannot have "-" in the name. More on dot notation and syntax [Here: MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)

so this:

```
o.data-cookieconsent="statistics"
```

should be written as:

```
o['data-cookieconsent']='statistics'
```